# Допустимо ли использовать yield return внутри блокировки?

Tags: c#, lock, yield

Есть два вопроса к коду, приведенному ниже:

- Допустимо ли использовать yield return внутри блокировки?
- Что произойдёт с блокировкой, когда мы будет крутить метод Get() в цикле foreach?

  ```
  public IEnumerable<SomeObject> Get()
  {
    _lock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
      foreach (var item in _dictionary)
      {
        yield return new SomeObject(item.Key, item.Value);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      _lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
  }

  private ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
  ```

Comment: О какой конкретно блокировке вы говорите?

Comment: ReaderWriterLockSlim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите, это возможно на уровне языка — компилятор не имеет возможности проверить. Но делать так не рекомендуется.

Общее правило такое: следует избегать вызова чужого кода под блокировкой. Допустим, вы нарушили правило и выполнили `yield` под блокировкой. Клиентский код может при этом сделать вызов в другой поток (если у нас нету многопоточности, то блокировки нам всё равно не нужны, правильно?).

```
foreach (SomeObject o in Get())
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Process(o));
}
```

Если в методе `Process` будет браться та же блокировка, у вас будет взаимная блокировка, и код зависнет: `Process` будет дожидаться отпускания блокировки, а блокирующий код — возвращения из yield (то есть, следующей итерации цикла).

Answer (score 14):

Ограниченно допустимо. Когда вы такую последовательность будете обходить в цикле foreach - то перед входом в цикл блокировка будет взята, а после выхода - освобождена. Также блокировка будет освобождена при любом прерывании цикла.

Однако, использование IEnumerable не ограничивается простыми циклами. При использовании блокировок всегда важно небольшое время удержания блокировки - а тут вы его растягиваете на не зависящее от вас время! Так можно легко и до взаимоблокировки доиграться.

Обычно лучше всего под блокировкой получить копию данных, и работать в дальнейшем уже с ней:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeObject> Get()
{
  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<SomeKey, SomeValue>> d;

  _lock.EnterReadLock();
  try
  {
    d = _dictionary.ToList();
  }
  finally
  {
    _lock.ExitReadLock();
  }

  foreach (var item in d)
  {
    yield return new SomeObject(item.Key, item.Value);
  }
}
```

Или даже вот так:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeObject> Get()
{
  _lock.EnterReadLock();
  try
  {
    return _dictionary.Select(item => new SomeObject(item.Key, item.Value)).ToList();
  }
  finally
  {
    _lock.ExitReadLock();
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, добрый человек!

Comment: Однако, если делать копию, то есть риск получить устаревшие данные. Тут пусть каждый сам решает что для него лучше: 1) заблокировать коллекцию, но быть уверенным, что данные консинстенты. 2) быстро разблокировать коллекцию, но быть готовым к устаревшим данным.

Comment: @StepanIvanenko существуют способы получить устаревшие данные даже под блокировкой :-)

Comment: Такой подход concurrent dictionary использует, если не ошибаюсь